# Docker: how to restart process inside of container?

Tags: docker

I have a set of tests which I would like to run on docker container. 
In the middle of the tests I am changing me test data and I need to restart JETTY.

What is the best way to do that?

I can imagine some options:

1. With SSH - but for the docker ssh is not the best option.
2. Python agent on docker to listen sockets - expose one more port, connect and restart jetty.

Maybe there are better ideas for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sounds like the process you're trying to restart is the primary process for the docker container (ie. the one you set in your Dockerfile if you have one, and when you run 'ps -ef' inside the container you would see the PID for your process set to 1).  If this is the case, then you cannot restart it from inside the container.  You should just restart the container itself:

```
docker restart <container_id>
```

Comment: It was almost one and half year ago... :) Indeed this is right way to restart the process. Only restart docker container. This is the main principle of docker solution itself .

Comment: @RobBailey Sorry for my comment, but It would be great if you will add some link which can describe the cause of that behavior.

Comment: @ЕвгенийМасленков https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ Not quite what you asked for, but the answer to your question gets philosophical.  Docker containers should handle one "concern", essentially do one thing.  That generally translates into "run a single process", useful in the context of lots of micoservices that interact with each other.  Tools like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm can more easily get info on (and act on) the health of that "concern" by watching for when the primary process goes down.  So, a container lives and dies by it's primary process.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the container and restart it.

Manual Way:

```
docker exec -it <containeridorname> /bin/bash
```

Or Automated Way:

```
docker exec -it <containeridorname> /restartjettycommand.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works fine. But now I have another problem. I start jetty with CMD command from Dockerfile. And it seems that I cannot restart this process :(

Comment: I'm not sure of the particulars for jetty myself.   An alternative would be to use something like runit or supervisord -- then you can exec into the container and simply restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an `entrypoint shell script`
you will need to build your docker file so that you can copy the files in to the container.

your `entrypoint.sh` or call it `runjettytests.sh`

pseudo code for that will look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar start.jar
$runTests
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop
cp dataset2 data/
java -jar start.jar
$runTests2
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop
exit(0)
```

clearly your use case may vary but thats a rough idea