# How do you setup script RELOAD/RESTART upon file changes using bash?

Tags: python, bash, unix, filesystems, reload

I have a Python Kafka worker run by a bash script in a Docker image inside a docker-compose setup that I need to reload and restart whenever a file in its directory changes, as I edit the code. Does anyone know how to accomplish this for a bash script?

**Please don't merge this** with the several answers about running a script whenever a file in a directory changes. I've seen other answers regarding this, but I can't find a way to run a script once, and then **stop, reload and re-run** it if any files change.

Thanks!

Comment: why shouldn't this be merged? You have one script `notify.sh` that checks if a file is changed. it calls another script `fileBeingEdited.sh` whenever it notices a change.

Comment: Because the script has to run in the first place, then reload. This is a different use case than only running when a file changes.

Comment: See Niels' answer for what I mean. You have one script constantly running, and it's just a wrapped that calls whatever script you've edited.

Comment: Thanks. This is a different solution than the other, similar questions about running scripts on file changes, so I hope this won't get merged :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to let docker start a wrapper script that simply starts the real script in the background.
Then in an infinite loop:

- using inotifywait the wrapper waits for the appropriate change
- then kills/stop/reload/... the child process
- starts a new one in the background again.

Comment: Interesting complication... the primary command of the container can't be restarted from inside the container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947865/docker-how-to-restart-process-inside-of-container

Comment: Why is this a complication? I would simply start the docker for these tests with this wrapper as the primary command. If you need to tweak the settings for a test consider making that a new Dockerfile that uses your "real" image you want to test as the FROM.